# EBay Enterprise IPO - what does this mean for Magento?

Tags: discussion

[eBay to Cut 2,400 Jobs and Explore Sale or IPO of Enterprise Unit](http://recode.net/2015/01/21/ebay-to-cut-2400-jobs-and-explore-sale-or-ipo-of-enterprise-unit/)

> EBay Enterprise revenue grew nine percent year-over-year in the fourth quarter, from $407 million to $443 million. **The unit includes its Magento division**, which makes software tools that power online retail sites for midsize brands.

and,

> “If a strategic or financial acquirer emerges, we’ll compare their offer to what we’d get from an IPO,” he said.

What would it mean for the community if eBay:

1. Sold Magento?
2. Went ahead with an IPO?

Would this include the community edition? What does this mean from a development stand point - and what will happen with the community?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mean anything for Magento.

If you look trough the original source http://investor.ebay.com/releasedetail.cfm?ReleaseID=892350 Magento is not really mentioned here, making all the fuzz about it unnecessary.

After putting PayPal into an own Business its not a surprising move to also separate other parts, and ebay Enterprise is a big big part.

One possible Adventage for ebay is, that buying and selling companies as part of `ebay enterprise` does not affect the `ebay` value directly anymore, making it more stable.
* This can mean they want to sell Magento, or one of the others
* It also can mean, they want to do some more risky buys in the future
* or they want to do nothing, and only prepare for a long long future

For the community this does mean nothing, they dont like the enterprise edition anyway, and it would mean no change for the community edition.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding CE/EE: CE always has been and continues to be the core of EE.

Comment: Amen to that. Really enjoyed the Mage2 AUA, thanks @benmarks.